# Anyone has experience using NightWatch with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I am using NightWatch for my e2e testing and want to move towards ES6 way of writing tests.
I was able to do it with Babel and it worked fine but I want to use typescript.
I could not find much documentation of NightWatch with TypeScript. Found some github repositories:

- https://github.com/rkavalap/NightWatchTest
- https://github.com/DonPage/Nightwatch-Typescript-example
- https://github.com/remojansen/TypeScriptTestingExamples

But these do not contain any detailed documentation around typescript.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but on other TS projects, I use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) as the interpreter.

```
ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch test.ts
```

You can do this with `@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch` as well.

Comment: This solution is not viable as of Nightwatch 1.3.5. The problem is that their codebase resolves test files using hardcoded references to a .js extension. Unfortunately there have already been a couple of PRs to address this that have gone stale and been closed. It looks like for now transpiling prior to running tests is the only reliable method.

Comment: I am sucessfuly runnig nightwatch 1.7.11 with ts-node, like this: `TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig.json node -r ts-node/register ./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch -c ./nightwatch.conf.ts test.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Try this GitHub [Nightwatch TypeScript example project](https://github.com/reallymello/nightwatchTutorials/tree/master/pomTypeScriptExample). It uses the [@types/nightwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/nightwatch) npm package for the Nightwatch type definition imports including support for the page object model and works with Nightwatch 2.0. The readme file in there has links to compiled documentation for further reading beyond the source code.

Answer (score -2):

There is no real difference using nightwatch with typescript. You can use setup somewhat similar to this:

nightwatch.ts:

```
var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');
import * as child_process from 'child_process';

var nightwatchOptions = { 
    config: './path/to/nightwatch.json', 
    env: 'default' 
  };

var httpServerProc = child_process.spawn(
      'node',
      [
        'node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server',
        'path/to/your/client_to_test',
        '-p 8082'
      ],
      {
        stdio: 'inherit'
      }
    );

nightwatch.runner(nightwatchOptions, function(success) 
{
    httpServerProc.kill('SIGINT');
});
```

Note - here I start `http-server`, you can use any other or maybe start it outside of the nightwatch testing procedure.

`nightwatch.json` - is your config settings for nightwatch.

Then all you need is to transpile `nightwatch.ts` as part of your solution and run resulting `nightwatch.js` under nodejs as usual.